# gazebo ros plugin make error: This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial to use gazebo plugins in ROS:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_plugins

but when I try to compile, I'm getting the following error:

```
gazebo_tutorials/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

and then a bunch of errors... I searched on the internet and I found the following related problem:

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create_desktop/issues/18

By the way, I'm using Gazebo 7 with Kinetic.

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258822/gazebo-ros-plugin-make-error:-this-file-requires-compiler-and-library-support-for-the-iso-c++-2011-standard/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2017-04-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-09**:
This seems like a problem with your compiler. Which compiler are you using, does it support C++11, and do you have C++11 support turned on?

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2017-04-09**:
I don't have C++11 support turned on. How I can turn on C++11 support on? I thought ROS is not compatible with C++11. I'm using the default compiler for catkin or how I can check which compiler I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) ROS Kinetic and newer require C++11 support. catkin uses the system's default compiler, so you should make sure that your default compiler supports C++11.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0